# Transact sql character order with symbols

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I see that T-SQL orders the varchar that starts with symbol in a special way.

Try this:

```
declare @test as table (val varchar(5) not null)

insert into @test 
values ('aaaa'), ('aabb'), ('-aaa'), ('+aaa'), ('ciao'), ('-bb'), ('+bb'), ('bau'), ('bcd')

select * from @test order by val
```

It returns:

1. +aaa
2. +bb
3. -aaa
4. aaaa
5. aabb
6. bau
7. -bb
8. bcd
9. ciao

So the minus sometime is ignored comparing letters, but is used comparing with other symbols...

I tried to search an explain to this behavior inside the MSDN but I don't find it...

There is some knew rule about it?

Comment: which version of SQL Server? I getting different result `+aaa
+bb
-aaa
-bb …..ciao` I am running on the Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)   ... I tried Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) with same result...

Comment: try replacing data type from varchar(5) to nvarchar(5)!!

Comment: What is your collation?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I get the same result as you using sql server 2016 - but I  am able to get the ordering as Hiten's if I order by ASCII(val)  - so I think the ordering is related to some combination of ASCII/ Unicode values ..

Comment: Your comment is useful, because if I do `select * from @test order by val COLLATE Latin1_General_BIN ASC` I am get the ordering as Hiten's,

Comment: @Perry, the sort order is determined by the column's [collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support). Windows collations (non-binary ones) use word-sort rules rather than single-character comparison to provide more natural dictionary ordering rules.

Comment: Dan, your comment is the answer. If you can add a link to a word-sort rule code or tutorial, I will accept your answer.